# CCActionMoveTo strange behavior for multiple sprites

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm seeing some very strange behaviour using cocos2d v3 and trying to move an array of sprites to a point in the center of the screen and then back to their original positions on the circle.

Here's where I initialize the sprites and add them to the scene in a circular arrangement around the center of the screen:

```
sprites = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:spriteCount];

for (int i = 0; i < spriteCount; i++) {

    CGFloat xPos = radius*sinf(i*2*M_PI/spriteCount) + screenCenter.x;
    CGFloat yPos = radius*cosf(i*2*M_PI/spriteCount) + screenCenter.y;

    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:imageFileNames[i%imageFileNames.count]];
    sprite.position = ccp(xPos, yPos);

    [self addChild:sprite];
    [sprites addObject:sprite];

}
```

And here is the code to move them all to the center of the screen and back to their original positions:

```
NSMutableArray *actionsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sprites.count];
for (CCSprite *sprite in sprites) {
    CCActionCallBlock *block = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        CGPoint pt = ccp(375/2.0, 667/2.0);
        CCActionMoveTo *moveToMiddle = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration/2.0f position:pt];
        CCActionMoveTo *moveToRing = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration/2.0f position:sprite.position];
        CCActionSequence *seq = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[moveToMiddle, moveToRing]];
        [sprite runAction:seq];
    }];
    [actionsArray addObject:block];
}
CCActionSpawn *actionSpawn = [CCActionSpawn actionWithArray:actionsArray];
```

For some reason that I cannot figure out, the first 2 sprites to be added to the scene do not move correctly; it appears as though every time they move, they move twice the distance (in both the x and y directions) as the other sprites in the array. All of the sprites except for the first 2 (i == 0 and i == 1) move correctly to (375/2.0, 667/2.0) and back to their original positions.

Is there any reason why those 2 sprites could be moving differently from the other sprites? And what is the best way to debug CCAction issues such as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has to do with your block/spawn usage. To begin, you don't need the block or to run a bunch of blocks using a spawn. You might as well do this (which would work to fix your issue):

```
for (CCSprite *sprite in sprites)
{
    CGPoint pt = ccp(375/2.0, 667/2.0);

    CCActionMoveTo *moveToMiddle = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration/2.0f position:pt];
    CCActionMoveTo *moveToRing = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration/2.0f position:sprite.position];
    CCActionSequence *seq = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[moveToMiddle, moveToRing]];

    [sprite runAction:seq];
}
```

The issue that is causing that to happen is that sprite 1 and 2 are having actions ran on them twice from your array of blocks. This problem, from the glance I was able to give it due to time constraints, has to do with an issue in:

```
CCActionSpawn *actionSpawn = [CCActionSpawn actionWithArray:actionsArray];
```

I'm not sure why but the spawn is running more iterations than it should. Maybe this is a bug in the version of cocos2d I tried it on. The spawn looks to be the culprit. Based on the code you provided, you don't need to use blocks/spawns in this manner so the above fix would work for you.

I hope this helped.

Edit:

A quick fix if you want to use blocks and spawns in this code is to simply call:

```
[sprite stopAllActions];
```

Before calling:

```
[sprite runAction...];
```

Comment: I'm actually creating the blocks and returning the spawn from a function because sometimes the spawn may run by itself but it may also be run in another spawn or sequence. So the issue with your fix (and I know this wasn't specified in my question) is that it will run the action immediately which may not be desired in all cases. Thanks for the answer though and I will look into the CCActionSpawn implementation to see if there is an obvious bug there.

Comment: I added an edit to my response that will allow you to use the blocks how you have it setup. I believe actions are not being removed when they should have and there was a similar bug issue filed on the cocos2d github https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-spritebuilder/issues/960.

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer as it points out a bug in cocos2d as the explanation for this issue. I still think there is likely a better workaround than calling stopAllActions though.